# Why does Jimmy hide going to law school from Chuck?

Tags: better-call-saul

I actually don't find it [realistic](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/119509/is-it-realistic-to-be-able-to-hide-going-to-law-school-part-time-from-your-law-f) that somehow Jimmy is *able to hide* going to law school and taking the bar 3x from Chuck and the entire HHM (including Kim?). But ok I'll bite.

I also don't find it realistic that Jimmy *does hide* going to law school and taking the bar 3x from Chuck and the entire HHM. Plus I think of those cases where employers will actually loan employees money to take classes. I think was kinda the case with Kim Wexler.

**Question**: Why? [Pride? Embarrassment / Shame?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89rKnkNDKdM)

Actually I also have tutored my younger sibling in maths all the time before when e was an engineering student. I think it would be very beneficial to ask your relatives for help in subjects you're taking that they've taken before. I don't see it as realistic that you go to law school but don't ask your own older sibling for any kind of help whatsoever from Day 1.

Comment: Regarding the employer paying for the classes, it's possible Jimmy arranged that and requested privacy.

Answer (score 2):

If you've watched more than the first few episodes of the series, you'll know

> Chuck McGill despises his brother, never wants his brother Jimmy to practice law, and so would probably have put up obstacles had he known Jimmy was trying to become a lawyer. (Letting anyone in HHM know would also probably mean Chuck would more easily find out.)

Comment: Chuck  wouldn't let him become a lawyer, but Jimmy didn't *know* that at the time.

Comment: @Mithoron: My interpretation is that after a lifetime spent with Chuck, Jimmy always knew how much Chuck despised him (and in particular how much Chuck would hate  Jimmy practicing law). Jimmy hoped that after successfully getting a law degree, Chuck would perhaps finally despise him less and perhaps even celebrate in his successes. (And indeed, initially after getting his law degree, Chuck did seem somewhat supportive of Jimmy's work as a public defender.) But before getting his law degree, Jimmy was cautious.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself in this comment :( The main reveal of the 1st season is that Jimmy can't work in HHM because of Chuck. His brother didn't want him there, not because of some hatred, if he even felt some of it, but because Jimmy could be dangerous - like we see in Breaking Bad. Jimmy didn't get that.